# Type Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException:xx\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-actionbar

I write my android project, when I run it, it has two problems that I can't solve it.. .
I read the other's same problem and answer of them, but my problem doesn't solve.

The problems are:

1. Type Error generating final archive `java.io.FileNotFoundException:xx\bin\resources.ap_` does not exist.
2. Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.

My project code is: src/com.divani.marzieh/ActionActivity:

```
package com.Divani.Marzieh;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class ActionActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

res/menu/activity_main_actions.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <!-- Refresh -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
          android:title="@string/action_refresh"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

What should I've done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Go to Window ->Android SDK manager and update Tools and Android 4.0. The same problem has occured for me but after trying this, it has solved my issues.

If that doesnt work, try updating everything.